# How to know when iron-list is finished creating html

Tags: javascript, templates, polymer, polymer-1.0

## Background

I am creating a a polymer iron-list and populating the list by setting the `items` property directly, like so: `document.getElementById('itemsList').items = data;`

When user changes category I change value of `items` in the above manner (retrieved with ajax). This works perfectly, but I now need to change the options in a `select` depending on my list category. I was able to do this using templating but it's cumbersome and may not even work later when the options need to be dynamic.

I would like to simply hide certain options with JavaScript but the `select` I want to manipulate is not present immediately after doing `.items = data`. I need a callback or some other way to detect when `iron-list` is done inserting HTML.

## Research

I looked through the documentation and couldn't find any references to callbacks or events other than `iron-resize`, and that doesn't look helpful.

I could potentially figure it out by listening `DOMNodeInserted` events but that's probably worse than the solution I've already got.

A `setTimeout` would also work, but is also a bad solution.

From miyamoto:  I could check `_itemsRendered` on iron-list which gets set to true, but I would probably need to do `setInterval` to check, also bad.

## Question

Is there a callback of any sort to let me know when `iron-list` is finished creating HTML? Failing that maybe an event or something else I could use to know when it's done?

## Update:

Answer seemd to be `dom-change` event, but now it seems it doesn't always fire. See [Polymer iron-list does not always fire dom-change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028750/polymer-iron-list-does-not-always-fire-dom-change-event)

Comment: I know `_itemsRendered` on `iron-list` gets set to true, but I can't think of a good way to listen for the change off the top of my head since it doesn't notify.

Comment: Oh, cool. If nothing else I could use that to do a potentially less egregious `setInterval` hack. Definitely let me know if you think of anything else!

Comment: Actually, upon re-reading the question. I think you're going about things all wrong. Is there a particular reason you want to set `items` on iron-list directly rather than a binding? I think templating would be the way to go. And you could use a computed binding to change the options for a `dom-repeat` for each item.

Comment: eg:`<iron-list>
<template>
    <select id="{{item.id}}">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{computeOptions(item, listCategory)}}" as="option">
            <option value="{{option.value}}" selected$="{{option.selected}}"></option>
        </template>
    </select>
</template>
</iron-list>`

Comment: Updated to clarify that `items` gets updated on category change as well. I set `items` when I get the data back from my ajax call because that seemed simplest. I don't know about polymer bindings. Would it work in this case? Do I need to bind in order to follow your example code?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this then. The [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) `computeItems` and `computeOptions` update their value as `data` or `listCategory` changes for the former, or `item` or `listCategory` for the latter changes. This allows polymer to manage all the data bindings for us: you just have to provide some function to compute it.

*NB*: That computing functions are not called until all dependent properties are define, i.e. not undefined.

```
<dom-module is="some-element">
<iron-list items="{{computeItems(data, listCategory)}}">
     <template>
          <select>
              <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{computeOptions(item, listCategory)}}" as="option">
                  <option value="{{option.value}}"></option>
              </template>
          </select>
     </template>
</iron-list>
</dom-module>

<script>
 Polymer({
    is: "some-element",
    properties: {
        data: Array,
        listCategory: String
    },
    computeOptions: function(item, listCategory){
        return item.options.filter(e=>e.category === listCategory)
    },
    computeItems: function(data, listCategory){ 
        return data.filter(e=>e.category === listCategory)
    }
 })
 </script>
```

Comment: Just getting back to this. I think we are going with the templating approach I mentioned earlier, but I am giving you a vote because I appreciate the effort and this looks like it would work.

Comment: If I want to use a computed binding to default the correct option to `selected` how would I do that? Doing `selected$="(computed)"` doesn't work because `selected="false"` is apparently the same as `selected="true"`. Also, just putting the computed binding in the option tag (idea was to return `selected` or empty string) seems to break the binding.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently trying to go a different route, but if anyone else needs to accomplish this it looks like the `dom-change` event should tell you.

#### Update:

This does not work in all cases, see [Polymer iron-list does not always fire dom-change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028750/polymer-iron-list-does-not-always-fire-dom-change-event)